# reactjs error - onChange is not a function error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, codesandbox, react-forms

I have created a field array with file input and a text field. Everything seems to works fine but when I try to upload a small image or typing something in the textfield, a Type error pops up with "onChange is not a function" message. How do I fix this error?

I have uploaded the code to codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-wildflower-6jlcl?file=/src/App.js

Comment: `<input ... onChange={(event)=> onChange({text:event.target.value})}/>` you are calling the onChange function but you never declared it. What exactly do you want to do with the input value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your whole code works as expected, **the error** you are getting is because `onChange` function is not declared. You are expecting it from the ***render prop*** of the `Controller` component but you are not getting it the right way.

***Line 71***

```
render={({ onChange }) => /** rest */ }
```

should be

```
render={({ field: { onChange } }) => /** rest */ }
```

You can see [an example of how this is done in react hook form docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller)

Answer (score 0):

well, **Firstly** you can't name the function as `onChange` as the default onChange already defined, **secondly** you never defined the function.

```
  const handleChange = (value) => console.log("onchange ", value);
```

then

```
<Controller
                  control={control}
                  name={`files.${index}.description`}
                  render={({ onChange }) => (
                    <input
                      style={{ border: "1px solid blue" }}
                      placeholder={"describe your file here"}
                      onChange={(event) =>
                        handleChange({ text: event.target.value }) // calling the handleChange function
                      }
                    />
```

I think it should work

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `onChange` function but you never declared it.

**1. The input field**

From what I can see you have to only do 2 small changes to get the input working correctly:

1. Declare another state variable:

`const [input, setInput] = useState("");`

2. Change your input `onChange` parameter to:

`onChange="event => setInput(event.target.value)"`

This should make the text input work.

**2. The file input field**

For the file input, make sure you read [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-file-input-tag)

> Because its value is read-only, it is an uncontrolled component in React. [...] You should use the File API to interact with the files.

Some more docs:
https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

[Forms as functional components with react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53519578/forms-as-functional-components-with-react)

https://rangle.io/blog/simplifying-controlled-inputs-with-hooks/